# A line avoiding an Algebraic group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field, and $G\subset (K,+)^3$ an algebraic subgroup (i.e. given as the zero sets of finitely many polynomial equations) of dimension 1.

> Is it clear that there is a line $L\subset K^3$ such that $$L\cap G=\{0\}?$$

Comment: If $0\not\in G$ then it cannot be true.  I assume by $0$ you mean the origin.

Comment: But $0\in G$ because it's a subgroup ;).

Comment: Ah you mean that kind of group.  I was thinking like an elliptic curve.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain When is an algebraic subset a group via the additive operation in $K^n$?  Only when it is $K^m$ for some $m\leq n$ no?

Comment: If the group operation is inherited from the additive operation and the subset is algebraic, then it must be a subspace $K^2$ or $K$.  In which case yes there's a line that intersects just at the origin.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: I think you're right, in which case my answer is a bit overkill - but I can only prove that in characteristic zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The story is rather complicated in characteristic $p$, but I think the answer of Drike takes care of it. On the other hand, Gregory Grant makes a claim that seems to me to be not right.

We’re working with the algebraic group $(K^3,+)$, which I think would usually be called $\mathbf G_{\mathrm a}^3$. Consider now the subgroup of $(K^3,+)$ given parametrically by $(t,t^p,t^{p^2})$, in other words as the common zeros of $X^p-Y$ and $X^{p^2}-Z$. Certainly a one-dimensional sub-algebraic-group. But I say that this one-dimensional subgroup is not contained in any plane through the origin.

Indeed, consider $\Bbb F_{P^3}$, and an element $\zeta\notin\Bbb F_p$ whose trace down to $\Bbb F_p$ is nonzero, call this trace $\xi$. Consider also the point $\mathfrak Z=(\zeta,\zeta^p,\zeta^{p^2})$ on our subgroup. Then $\mathfrak Z'=(\zeta^p,\zeta^{p^2},\zeta)$ and $\mathfrak Z''=(\zeta^{p^2},\zeta,\zeta^p)$ all are in our subgroup, and are all on the hyperplane $X+Y+Z=\xi$ that doesn’t contain the origin, and so isn’t a subgroup. In particular, our one-dimensional subgroup is not contained in any plane through the origin.

Comment: many thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a subspace of $K^3$ that is also a subgroup of the additive group $\langle K,+\rangle$, then that subspace must be a plane or a line.  In this case choose any line that does not lie in the plane and the intersection will be just the origin.

Comment: I am sorry but why is an additive algebraic subgroup of (K,+)^3 a plane, a line, or the origin? It need not be a K-vector space, a priori.

Comment: Well take any non-zero point.  It and all of its multiples must be in the subgroup.  But there's a line that intersects all of those points right?  And a line cannot intersect an algebraic surface in infinitely many points unless it is contained in the surface.  So for every point in the surface it contains the entire line through the origin and that point.  If a surface contains every line through one of its points and the origin then that surface must be a plane or a line, no?

Comment: Actually maybe it's not so obvious.  A cone satisfies that it contains the line connecting any point to the origin.  But if it has two points not on the same line then it must have the entire lattice and therefore the entire plane containing that lattice.  So I still think it's true.

Comment: "a line cannot intersect an algebraic surface in infinitely many points unless it is contained in the surface" why so ? This would show that G is a K-vector space, withdrawing any ambiguity !

Comment: @Drike You also need to know if two points don't lie on the same line that $P+Q\in G$.  But the same argument shows that the lattice $\{mP+nQ\mid m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ generated by $P$ and $Q$ must be in $G$ and therefore the entire plane containing that lattice must be in $G$.  Because of a plane is intersected with $G$ the intersection must be a curve and so cannot contain an entire lattice.

Comment: @Drike Over an algebraically closed field an algebraic set either has finitely many points or uncountably many.  You can't have a discrete set of infinitely many points being algebraic for the same reason you can't have a polynomial in one variable with infinitely many zeros.

Comment: "Well take any non-zero point. It and all of its multiples must be in the subgroup. But there's a line that intersects all of those points right?" Ok but what if char K= p ? then you are considering only finitely many points.

Comment: @Drike Even if char $K=p$, since $K$ is algebraically closed it has uncountably infinite cardinality.

Comment: if char $K=p$, and $x\in G\setminus\{0\}$, then $\mathbf F_px\subset G$, but $\mathbf F_px$ is finite, so how do you conclude that $G$ contains the line $Kx$ ?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Well for one thing we are assuming $G$ is a proper subgroup right?  It's obviously not true if $G=K^3$.  Still doesn't answer your question on char $p$, I'll have to think about that some more.

Comment: I won't be offended if you revoke the "check" on my answer.

Comment: It is proper since it has dimension 1. I am also still struggling with how to prove that a discrete algebraic subset of $K^n$ is finite. For $n=1$, it follows from the fact that $K[X]$ is Euclidian.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the dimension $1$ thing.  That should make it a lot easier, let me think about it for a minute.

Comment: See my answer below, which is really an extended comment to you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Gregory Grant noticed, if $K$ has **characteristic $\bf 0$**, then $G$ must be a $K$-vector space, hence a line, so the answer is obvious.

If $K$ has **characteristic $\bf p$**, I'd consider the morphism of varieties $\varphi:K\times G\rightarrow K^3,\ (k,g)\mapsto kg$ and say that if $Im\varphi$ is a variety, it is of dimension no more than $dim(K\times G)=2$, hence one can take any $y\notin Im\varphi$. The line $L=Ky$ will do the job.

I am trying to use as little machinery as possible, so any other answer with fewer technicalities is welcome !

Comment: This looks right to me, but I’m no good at AG. Plus one.

Comment: Oh wait. My presumed example seems not to like your argument either. I don’t understand why $\mathrm{Im}\varphi$ being a variety forces it to lie in a plane.

Comment: You are right, I just saw your answer and edited my answer acccordingly. My mistake is to have thought that $Im\varphi$ was a K-vector space, but it is not !

Comment: I  like this one much better, and also better than the proof I was struggling to construct. In other language than yours, you are taking the cone of $G$ through the origin, and that’s a 2-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Indeed, for the example I constructed, this cone has general point $(st,st^p,st^{p^2})$, and the single polynomial of which this is a zero is $Y^{p+1}-ZX^p$.